# Problem reading file using stringWithContentsOfFile:

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch, ios, uitextview

In my app I have to read an XML file and display it in a `UITextView`. To do this I tried the code below. This code is resulting in a crash; can any one tell me the exact mistake? I hope I wrote well. Please help me out. Thank you.

```
-(IBAction)xmlParse{

    NSString *xmlPath=[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] applicationDocumentDirectory]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xmlFile/toc.xml"];
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSString *fileContent=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath usedEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
    xmlDisplay.text=fileContent;

}
```

Comment: Please add the console error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
NSString *fileContent=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath usedEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
```

with

```
NSString *fileContent=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
```

you should not ignore the `assing argument 2 of 'stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:' makes pointer from integer without a cast` warning the compiler shows you.

Comment: +1 Thank you its working can you please give me more details for both the statements diff.

Comment: the method with `usedEncoding:` tries to figure out the encoding for you. And it will assign the used encoding to the pointer you supply. So the method tries to assign a value to the address 1 (the value of NSASCIIStringEncoding). And since this is a address where you should not write you'll get a bad access exception. For more details you should see the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing same issue earlier . it is batter to save xml file inside document Directory itself not in any sub Folder .try to save in to Document Directory . hope should work....

or u can try

```
-(IBAction)xmlParse{

NSString *xmlPath=[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] applicationDocumentDirectory]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xmlFile/toc.xml"];
NSError *error=nil;
NSString *fileContent=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath usedEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
if(nil!=fileContent)
xmlDisplay.text=fileContent;
```